# Setting multiple environment variables in a shell spawned via windows batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a batch file that spawns a shell with a modified path with the following command:

```
cmd /K set PATH=%PATH%;<additional path locations>
```

I want to set additional environment variables for the spawned shell as well. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add another variable on a new line using `set` as shown in your example. You will also want to remove the /K switch from the first line as execution will stop after that line.

```
set NEWVAR=SOMETHING
```

will create a new variable called `NEWVAR` with the value `SOMETHING`. If you wish to keep the same behavior and keep `cmd` open with the /K switch just put it at the end.

example:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Folder;
set NEWVAR=SOMETHING
echo %NEWVAR%
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked like I wanted it to.  I put cmd /K at the end because I wanted to use the shell after it had finished executing my commands.

Comment: You can also write a batch that makes all necessary changes to the environment and then simply start your `cmd` instance with `cmd /k setvars.cmd`. This is for example how Visual Studio sets up its command prompt.

Answer (score 3):

You could also combine them into a single line as follows:

`set A=foo & B=bar & C=baz`

This way, you could avoid having to modify the original script and run it like so:

`set A=foo & B=bar & C=baz & c:\path\to\foo.bat`

Comment: When running this from an `npm`/`yarn` script, I had to prefix each variable assignment with `set`. e.g. `set A=foo & set B=bar & set C=baz & c:\path\...`

Answer (score 0):

summing up what others here posted, along with info gleaned from another post, here's what I saved into my `internet_proxy_setup.bat` file:

`cmd /K "set http_proxy=http://proxy.mycorp.com:1234&& set https_proxy=http://proxy.mycorp.com:1235&& echo In HTTPS Proxy Shell&& cd %~dp0"`

where the `cd %~dp0` just changes the shell to the same directory that the `.bat` file is stored in