# Setting and getting Windows environment variables from the command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I want to set an environment variable from the command prompt and then be able to access it globally (for instance, I should see it by going to System -> Environment Variables).

When I use the set command, it isn't accessible in a new cmd session.

```
set NEWVAR=SOMETHING
echo %NEWVAR%
```

Related questions:

- *[Is there any command line tool that can be used to edit environment variables in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/13783/)*
- *[Setting multiple environment variables in a shell spawned via windows batch script](https://superuser.com/questions/23048/)*

Comment: setx variable value - then restart Command Prompt

Comment: This is fully documented here, for command line + powershell - http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/

Answer (score 348, accepted):

To make the environment variable accessible globally you need to set it in the registry. As you've realised by just using:

> set NEWVAR=SOMETHING

you are just setting it in the current process space.

According to [this page](http://ss64.com/nt) you can use the [`setx`](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command:

> setx NEWVAR SOMETHING

`setx` is built into Windows 7, but for older versions may only be available if you install the [Windows Resource Kit](http://ss64.com/links/windows.html#kits)

Comment: Note that you need to specify quota, for example : `setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"` will work. But `setx JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45` will give you syntax errors

Comment: @MD.MohiuddinAhmed That's because there are spaces in the path.

Comment: this can damage your path because of a 1024 character limit! - see https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx

Comment: You can check the command result by using `echo %NEWVAR%`. Current cmd will cache the Environment Variables so closing the current cmd and opening a new one will be required to see the changes done.

Comment: And for Windows Terminal, you currently (nov 2020) need to close all instances and restart.

Answer (score 49):

We can also use "setx var variable /M" to set the var to system environment variable level instead of user level.

Note: This command should be run as administrator.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `setx env var [/M]` as mentioned above.
If it doesn't take effect you can use `refreshenv` to refresh environment variables. You don't have to restart your computer, explorer.exe or your command prompt to do that.

Edit: apparantly refreshenv doesn't come naturally with Windows, so here's the source: https://pastebin.com/1fJqA0pT
Save as RefreshEnv.cmd and place it in a folder that's included in your PATH environment variables

Comment: +1 for mentioning 'refreshenv' - I'd never come across that before!

Answer (score 6):

System variables can be set through CMD and registry 
For ex. **reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH**

All the commonly used CMD codes and system variables are given here: [Set Windows system environment variables using CMD](http://www.mindxmaster.com/2017/03/modify-add-windows-system-environment-variables.html).

Open CMD and type **Set**

You will get all the values of system variable.

Type **set java** to know the path details of java installed on your window OS.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: It's close, though.  Using REG ADD may accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that if you are using the /s parameter with setx in order to set environment variables on a remote computer, the "Remote Registry" service needs to be running on the target machine or else you will receive a "ERROR: The specified operation could not be completed."

(I have asked Microsoft to update their [TechNet article on setx](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks) to include this information.)