# Is there a way to set Windows environment variables from the command line PERMANENTLY

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting and getting windows environment variables from the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt)

Is there any way to set permanently set an environment variable system wide from the command line in Windows?

something like

```
>systemset newVar=foo
```

or a file to edit would work well too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the MS utility "Setx" to make permanent changes form the command-line.

Here's a [direct link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=dc2d3339-8f36-4fba-a406-2a2a2ad7208c) to the Windows 2000 version (works in XP, etc.).

You can also get it in the [Windows XP SP2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=49AE8576-9BB9-4126-9761-BA8011FABF38&displaylang=en) pack.

> It is
>   not part of the standard Windows XP
>   setup but a command-line tool called
>   setx.exe is included in the Windows XP
>   Service Pack 2 Support Tools. This
>   tool extends the set command so that
>   permanent changes in the environment
>   variables can be made. For example, to
>   add a folder C:\New Folder to the
>   path, the command would be  setx path
>   "%PATH%;C:\New Folder"

Comment: It's part of Windows since at least Vista, though.

Comment: Good point, forgot to mention that. :)

Comment: It is possible to do the same from **System Properties** > **Advanced** > **Environment Variables**, or registry `HKCU\Environment`.