# cmd.exe SET command does not save values for new cmd.exe sessions

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Set Permanent Environmental Variable in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/135056/set-permanent-environmental-variable-in-windows-xp)
>   [Is there a way to set Windows environment variables from the command line PERMANENTLY](https://superuser.com/questions/119838/is-there-a-way-to-set-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-line-permane)

The **set** command does not save values between cmd.exe sessions. How can I save environmental values between new cmd.exe sessions?

For example the set command will work for my current session only:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Mingw\bin
```

Upon restarting cmd.exe my *path* string has been reset.

**Possible solution:** .bashrc or .bash_profile equivalent for DOS

Comment: FYI, `cmd.exe` is **not DOS**. It is a native 32-bit Windows program. The _only_ thing in common with MS-DOS is the command syntax.

Comment: @grawity: Not even that, in places. For example the `for` statement has differing (and incampatible) behavior.

Comment: @Johannes: Depends on whether "command prompt extensions" is on, I think.

Comment: @grawity: Not even then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use SETX as per answers in this thread (linked from the right hand side here as a related question):
[Is there a way to set Windows environment variables from the command line PERMANENTLY](https://superuser.com/questions/119838/is-there-a-way-to-set-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-line-permane)

Answer (score 3):

Add/change them from Global environment variables. To access this (Assuming Windows XP as your OS ), right click on `My Computer` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced Tab` -> `Environment Variables` and add whatever is required.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

Assuming Windows XP Pro:

1. Go into c:\windows\system32\autoexec.nt and change to add the path there.
2. Right click My Computer, go into properties, Advanced, Environmental Variables, change there.
3. Create a login script.  Right click My Computer, go into Manage.  Go into Local Users and Groups, then Users.  Right click the login, choose properties, go into Profile and set th Logon script.  The default location it looks for login scripts are c:\windows\system32\repl\import\scripts.

Comment: What is a login script going to do? Using set only applies to that specific cmd instance. It will run and then not affect any following command prompt sessions.

Comment: You can set the environment in the login.  It then that gets forced into the environment variable space.  Subsequent command prompt sessions inherit those variables.  SetX or Setenv can be used here.

Comment: You don't need to use setx or setenv more than once, so doing it every login is unnecessary.

Comment: True, it should modify the registry.  I isn't necessary to keep pushing it, but at least there is a stake marker somewhere that you did push something.  If you did it from the command line or from the GUI, you don't know that it happened later.  Keeping it here is redundant on boot, but a permanent place to look later to see what you did.

Comment: echo %path% should be enough to show you what you've added to your path.

Answer (score 0):

To get **Windows** to save environment variables, Right-click on My Computer, click `Properties`, then `Advanced` | `Environment Variables` and edit it there.

Comment: Is there a .bashrc or .bash_profile equivalent for DOS?