# Command Line Tool for Adding To Your Windows PATH, Permanently?

Tags: windows, command-line, path

Is there a way to permanently modify your PATH from the command line?

I find myself often trying to run a command or two on the DOS prompt, and find out it's not on my path.  I manually find the location, use the tool with a long winded path, and forget to add it to my path so I don't have to do that rigmarole again.

Ideally I'd love to say addToMyPath.exe [dir] and it would auto add to my regkey for the path.  Anything like that exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting and getting windows environment variables from the command prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt), [Is there a way to set Windows environment variables from the command line PERMANENTLY](http://superuser.com/questions/119838/is-there-a-way-to-set-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-line-perman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source [How to update PATH variable permanently from cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358265/how-to-update-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd-windows/10411111#10411111) by panny:

Use

> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Something\bin"

The new `PATH` will **not** apply to your current `cmd.exe`.

If you look in the registry or in a new `cmd.exe` with `set path` you will see the new value.

See [SETX.exe (Resource Kit, Windows 7)](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) for more information on the `setx` command.