# Chocolatey needs permissions for 'Windows Security Client'

Tags: windows-7, windows, chocolatey

I'm trying to software using Chocolatey onto a Windows 7 Enterprise machine, but it requires permissions for "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Microsoft Security Client". Since this computer is supposed to be pretty secure, then I guess it's a good thing I don't have any access to any Microsoft Security Essentials stuff.

Why does Chocolatey even need access to this stuff and can I skip it? There's no guarantee I'll get the permissions. This happens with our own custom packages AND, for example, the public Git package.

The full error:

> Requested registry access is not allowed. Failed to open subkey named
>   'Microsoft Security Client' for
>   'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall',
>   likely due to permissions: Requested registry access is not allowed.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This registry key is used to define how an application should be uninstalled.
A non-administrator account does not have the permissions to modify this key.

As a workaround, you could install Chocolatey in a non-administrative mode.
In this mode it will install applications in a specified folder
without requiring administrator permissions.

For details see:

- [Chocolatey : Non-Administrative install](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation#non-administrative-install)
- [Chocolatey as non-admin user](https://superuser.com/questions/1095475/chocolatey-as-non-admin-user)